# Does quasi-finite and "étale locally" closed enough to imply finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes of finite type. Then it is well-known that

$f$ is finite iff $f$ is quasi-finite and proper.

And proper is separated and universally closed. But I'm wondering if one can check the universally closed property just by "étale locally", i.e. for any $S\to Y$ étale, $X\times_YS\to S$ is closed. So my question is: if $f$ is quasi-finite, separated and "étale locally" closed then is $f$ finite? Many thanks!

Comment: Just a minor comment: I think the terminology 'étale locally' might be a little misleading... since - at least in my mind - this would mean there exists an étale cover of the base such that the corresponding base-change is closed; this would of course equivalent to 'ordinary' closed-ness since this is one of the properties which satisfy fpqc descent. By the way props for the great question:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I have made a mistake (which is possible, so please check), this miraculously seems to be true.

I say 'miraculously' as, without the quasi-finiteness assumption, it fails woefully. Indeed, if $Y$ is the spectrum of an algebraically closed field, then every etale $Y$-scheme is just a disjoint union of points (see [Tag 02GL](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GL)), and so, in fact, every morphism $X\to Y$ of schemes is 'etale universally closed'.

But, it seems that quasi-finiteness saves the day. I think the motto for this is that by [Zariski's Main Theorem](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05K0), $f\colon X\to Y$ being quasi-finite but not finite is a condition on 'having missing points at the boundary' of $X$ in $Z$ for some finite map $g\colon Z\to Y$, and this is witnessed by the non-Zariski closedness of the map etale locally on the target. Basically etale locally one can make precise that $f(X)$ looks like $g(Z)$ minus some closed points, which shouldn't be closed.

---

Here is a precise statement and proof.

> **Claim:** Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a quasi-finite, separated, and finite type map between schemes. Suppose that for every etale map $U\to Y$ the induced map $X\times_Y U\to U$ is closed. Then, $f$ is finite.

*Proof:* Let us fix a point $y$ of $Y$. Recall then that we have the Henselization of $Y$ at $y$:

$$\varprojlim U=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}^h),$$

as $U$ runs over affine elementary etale neighborhoods of $(Y,y)$ (see [Tag 02LD](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02LD)). Let us then observe that

$$X\times_Y \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}^h)=X\times_Y \left(\varprojlim U\right)=\varprojlim (X\times_Y U).$$

As each $X\times_Y U\to U$ is quasi-compact and closed, we deduce that $X\times_Y \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}^h)\to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}^h)$ is quasi-compact and closed by [FK, Chapter 0, Theorem 2.2.13].

Moreover, by [Tag 01ZO](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01ZO) we see that if $X\times_Y \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}^h)\to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}^h)$ is finite, then $X\times_Y U\to U$ is finite for some $U$. Thus, if we can show that $X\times_Y \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}^h)\to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}^h)$ is finite for all $y$ in $Y$, then we will have an etale cover of $Y$ for which the pullback is finite, and thus $X\to Y$ is finite by [Tag 0426](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0426). Thus, all in all, we see that we may assume that $Y=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ where $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is a [Henselian local ring](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04GF).

Now, as $f\colon X\to Y=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is finite type and separated, and $Y$ is quasi-compact and quasi-zeparated, we know by Zariski's main theorem that we may factorize $f$ as

$$X\xrightarrow{j}Z\xrightarrow{g}Y,$$

where $j$ is a quasi-compact open embedding and $g$ is finite. In particular, we have that $Z=\mathrm{Spec}(S)$ for some finite $R$-algebra $S$. By [Tag 04GH](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04GH) we see that $S=S_1\times \cdots\times S_n$ with each $R\to S_i$ a finite local ring map. Note that by intersecting $j(X)$ with each $\mathrm{Spec}(R_i)$, we may assume that $n=1$, and so $S=S_1$.

Thus, we have a factorization of $f$

$$X\xrightarrow{j}\mathrm{Spec}(S)\xrightarrow{g}\mathrm{Spec}(R),$$

with $g$ finite, $f$ closed, and $j$ a quasi-compact open embedding. We then win if we can show that $j$ is an isomorphism. But, as $f(X)$ is non-empty and closed, it is of the form $V(J)$ for some proper ideal $J$ of $R$, but as $R$ is local this must contain $\mathfrak{m}$. But, note that

$$g^{-1}(\mathfrak{m})=\mathrm{Spec}(S\otimes_R (R/\mathfrak{m}))=\mathrm{Spec}(S/\mathfrak{m}S),$$

which, as $R\to S$ is local, must be a single point. In particular, we see that $j(X)$ contains the closed point of $\mathrm{Spec}(S)$. But, this implies that it's everything. Indeed, if not, then its complement is of the form $V(I)$ for some proper ideal $I$ of $S$, and thus must contain the closed point of $\mathrm{Spec}(S)$ which is a contradiction. $\blacksquare$

Of course, if you inspect the above proof, you see that it really suffices to know that for all $y$ in $Y$, and all elementary etale neighborhoods $U\to Y$ of $(Y,y)$ that $X\times_Y U\to U$ is closed. Think of $Y=\mathrm{Spec}(k)$, where $k$ is a non-separably closed field, to see why this is (very slightly) stronger.

---

I would like to take this opportunity to advertize a neat result, which has been helpful (at least once) in my research. Namely, even without assuming that $f\colon X\to Y$ is quasi-finite, it is enough to check universal closedness for $U\to Y$ which are *smooth*. In fact, simultaneously surprising and unsurprising, it suffices to check that the map is closed after pullback to $\mathbb{A}^n_Y$ for all $n\geqslant 0$ (see [Tag 05JX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05JX)).

---

This is to address a comment in the questions. Namely, let's discuss the non-finite map

$$f\colon \mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}-\{1\}\to \mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C},\qquad x\mapsto x^2,$$

and how it fails this 'etale universal closedness'.

Namely, $f$ is itself closed, essentially because $f(Z)=g(Z)$ where
$$g\colon \mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C},\qquad x\mapsto x^2,$$

and $g$ is finite. That said, consider the etale map
$$\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}\to\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C},\qquad x\mapsto x^2.$$

If we base change this map we arrive at the map

$$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}\times(\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}-\{1\}): x^2=y^2\}\to \mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}},\qquad (x,y)\mapsto x.$$

This source is actually isomorphic as a $\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}$-scheme to

$$(\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}-\{1\})\sqcup (\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}-\{-1\
)$$

(where the structure map to $\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}$ are the natural inclusions on eacn component) via the map

$$(\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}-\{1\})\sqcup (\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}-\{-1\})\to \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}\times(\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}-\{1\}): x^2=y^2\},$$

which on the $(\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}-\{1\})$-component sends $x$ to $(x,x)$ and on the $(\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}-\{-1\})$-component sends $x$ to $(x,-x)$. In particular, we see that we run into a problem as each connected component is closed, but their images in $\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}$ are not.

**References:**

[FK] https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.4734.pdf

Comment: This is crazy hahah was not expecting this to be true and spent my morning looking for a counterexample

Comment: @ThomasManopulo Well, despite the OP accepting this answer, I still have some minor fear it could be wrong -- it makes some intuitive sense, but doesn't seem like it should be true.

Comment: Hey Alex! I was thinking about the following example: if $f : \mathbf{A}^1_{\mathbf{C}} \setminus \{1\} \to \mathbf{A}^1_{\mathbf{C}}$ is the restriction of the map $x \mapsto x^2$ to the complement of the point $\{1\}$, then this isn't proper since it's not finite - for instance (bc it's q.finite). But shouldn't all its étale base changes $S\to \mathbf{A}^1_\mathbf{C}$ still be closed, since $\mathbf{A}^1_\mathbf{C}$ is simply connected? I might be messing up something silly here :p

Comment: @ThomasManopulo Hey Thomas. I made an edit above to address your question. The part you need to be careful is that $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ having trivial etale fundamental group only tells you that all connected, finite etale covers of $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ are trivial. So, if the OP had required that $S\to Y$ be finite etale, then your example would work. But, as the above example shows, you can take, for instance, compositions of finite etale covers and open embeddings.

Comment: Ahhhh right!! Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Comment: For the latest comment, did you perhaps mean $\Bbb A^1 -\{1\}$? Currently the point you're excluding there is $0$.

Comment: @KReiser Fixed! Thanks.